# Apply conditional formatting to compare multiple rows and columns to a reference column

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a Google sheet of this form:

**A**   B   C   D   E
1 **A1** B1 C1 D1 E1
2 **A2** B2 C2 D2 E2
3 **A3** B3 C3 D3 E3
4 **A4** B4 C4 D4 E4
5 **A5** B5 C5 D5 E5

The column $A contains reference values to which I want to compare the rest of the table.
The formatting I want to do is simple:

`For each row x of the table:`

`For each column β in columns (B:Z) of the table:`

- *apply color green*: `if the cell βx is greater than $Ax`
- *apply color red*: `if the cell βx is less or equal to $Ax`

I have tried a custom formula with `=$A1:$A>B1:Z on range B1:Z`, but it doesn't work.

This formula works on only one column (for example B): `=$A1:$A>B1:B on range B1:B`.
I'm just now looking for a way to apply this formatting to all columns at once, without having to rebuild the conditional format manually for each column (hundreds of columns is a lot..)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try:

[image: SO24564331 example]

with the Range:'s adjusted to suit. (If that is not what you require it should be fairly easy to fix.)